# Workout net cost based on gross with 3 taxes added

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to work out the net cost where I've been provided a gross cost.  There are 3 types of taxes applied to the gross cost so need to calculate these too.

Example:

```
Gross total = 10,000k

Tax 1 = 5% of unit cost
Tax 2 = 8% of unit cost and Tax 1 added together
Tax 3 = 10% of unit cost
```

I manually working out by typing the amount 8103.73 but need to add a formula in this cell instead:

Example with manual entry

[image]

Comment: Thanks for telling us what you want. Now please tell us what you have tried and where you ran into trouble. Please include that in your question.

Comment: Your combined tax is 23.4%, so your multiplier to get your gross cost from unit cost is simply 1.234

Comment: Afaik you want to know the inverse direction calculating from 10,000.00 to Unit Cost. Assuming Tax percentages in B2:B4 and Gross Cost in C5 this is a simple formula entered in C1: `=ROUND(C5/(1+B2+B2*B3+B3+B4),2)` where the divisor = 1 plus the accumulated tax percentages ~> 1 + 0.234 = 1.234; 10000 :/ 1.234 results in 8,103.73:-) @VinodVarsani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I manually working out by typing the amount `8103.73` but need to add a formula in this cell (i.e. calculating the Unit Cost base) instead:*

You want to calculate the inverse direction. Basically you would divide 10,000 through (1 + tax1% + tax2% + tax3%), however the 2nd tax percentage is not only applied upon the unit cost base, but upon the first taxation as well. So you need to include the multiplication of tax1% * tax2% as additional part.

Assuming tax percentages in `B2:B4` and the **Gross Cost** in `C5` this is a simple formula entered in `C1`:

```
=ROUND(C5/(1+B2+B2*B3+B3+B4),2)
```

- where the divisor = 1 plus the accumulated tax percentages,
- i.e. 1 + 0.234 = 1.234
- so 10000 :/ 1.234 results in `8,103.73`

Comment: Thank you for this. This has helped alot. I've tried to replicate this formula if there are up to 5x Tax option but it's doesn't work fully. I'll continue to try alternative but thankyou for far for the help.

Comment: For the 5 taxes i've used the formula =ROUND(10,000/(1+Tax%1+Tax1%*Tax2%+Tax2%+Tax3%+Tax4%+Tax5%),2) . The total gross I get doesn't total up to 10,000 with the taxes added in.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, feel free to accept it by ticking the green checkmark next to the answer. - Referring to your comment: There can always be some rounding differences. Could you edit some sample data to allow to reproduce your issue? @VinodVarsani